# How to connect to MySQL server using SSL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, keytool

Hi I am trying to sign in to my MySQL db remotely using java. I created a remote account that requires SSL. I did this by following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Now once I am trying to connect to the DB Java throws this error:

`WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.`

So I added this to my URL:

```
       + "&useSSL=true"
      + "&requireSSL=true";
```

But now it requires me to give it a `trustStore`and a `trustStorePassword`. Where or how can I find/create these?

My MySQL server is running on a VPS ubuntu server btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and import the server's certificate with a keytool command :

```
keytool -import -alias mysql -file server-cert.pem -keystore mycerts -storepass changeit
```

where server-cert.pem is the mysql's certificate (which you can get by following the instructions under this link: http://do.co/2FaIK8F, mycerts will be your trustStore (will be created by the command), and trustStorePassword is changeit (of course, choose one)

server-cert.pem is the file mentioned in your tutorial, which contains the server's certificate.

You then need to add the `trustStore` to your Java using this code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mycerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Where *changeit* is the password you chose in the keytool command and where *mycerts* is the path to the trustStore.

Comment: Where should I execute the keytool command? On my ubuntu server?

Comment: This is your Java client which is complaining, right ? Use keytool anywhere you want while you have your files there, but at the end you will need to have this truststore on your client. Either use it as the default truststore, or use system properties (javax.net.ssl.trustStore / javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword)

Comment: its eclipse complaining, it's giving me these errors. So where can I enter the `keytool` command?

Comment: open a command window if you're on Windows, a shell if you're on Linux. This is the basics that you need to know or learn or you will be blocked often on stupid things.

Comment: so I need to open cmd in the eclipse project folder and run the command there??? Cuz I dont think keytool is a command in CMD

Comment: If you have Java installed on your computer, keytool comes with it in the bin directory. Open a CMD. Just try.

Comment: check the program is on your computer : tree /A /F c: | find "keytool" . If you can't find, you still can run it on your server and transfer your truststore to your Eclipse.

Comment: I found keytool.exe in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin` and ran the cmd command in that folder but it gave me the error: `keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: server-cert.pem (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: On my ubuntu server I get this error: `root@vps520749:~# keytool -import -alias mysql -file -server-cert.pem -keystore mycerts -storepass 6cnanF5B
The program 'keytool' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: apt install <selected package>
root@vps520749:~#
`

Comment: "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: server-cert.pem" Of course you have to give the real path to this file that you took from Mysql and that you generated in your tutorial. You need to copy it from mysql to your computer. The whole command, and I tested it, is working : "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias mysql -file c:\Users\myself\Desktop\server-cert.pem -keystore c:\Users\myself\Desktop\cacerts -storepass 5cnanF5B / Replace to fit your environment. Once done, your java client needs to use it (see my 1st comment)

Comment: Ohh thanks mate I got it working thanks for the help\

Comment: Good. I will appreciate if you vote/mark the answer or the comment as usefull, it takes time to answer you know.